# How to pass function scope (not context)?

Tags: javascript, this

Can you please help me to find the error in the code? I need to pass one method's scope to another method.

```
var obj = {
    doIt: function() {
        var a = 10;
        this.doThat.call(this);
    },
    doThat: function() {
        console.log(a);
    }
};

obj.doIt();
```

Comment: You can't pass the variables in one scope to another implicitly. You will need to pass `a` to `doThat` or add `a` a public property of the `obj`

Comment: The sample code might be a bit to dummed down though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that there is difference between `context` and `scope`. scope is going to be something which will dictate which variables are accessible from a particular site whereas context is what will be the value of this at particular site or inside a function.

so if you want to use value of `a` in function `doThat` you need to bind value of `a` with `this` which is context in function `doIt` like: `this.a = 10;` and then access it using `console.log(this.a)` inside function `doThat`

Comment: Now it's clear for me. I didn't see the difference between context and scope before.Is it possible to send scope to another function? Or it's the only one way how to achive it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `a` in the scope of context, you can try this.

```
var obj = {
    doIt: function() {
        this.a = 10;
        this.doThat.call(this);
    },
    doThat: function() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
};

obj.doIt();
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without make 'a' variable 'global' for all methods?

Answer (score 1):

You *do* pass the "context" (aka `this`) around. `a` however, is not part of the current context, but of the current scope. So you either move `a` into the context:

```
 var obj = {
   doIt: function() {
    this.a = 10;
    this.doThat();
  },
  doThat: function() {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
};
```

Or you directly pass the value of `a` into doThat:

```
   //...
  this.doThat(a);

  doThat(a) { /*...*/ }
```